# restore button for in-app purchases error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I got a problem while restoring an in-app purchase in my app

I already applied this lines of codes in my project:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

but it calls this function

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

What must I need to do to avoid getting this error? and call this function:

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what kind of error did you have?

Comment: actually sir, I wish that my in-app purchases should be restored, but it does not call the function - (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue instead it calls the - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error");
}

Comment: Check the Error Description what it is telling by `NSLog("%@",[error Description])`

Comment: Here's what the error says: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=5002 "An unknown error has occurred" UserInfo=0xa12d1e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error has occurred}
What does it mean sir? thanks

Comment: have you set a valid debit or credit card for your account for the purchasing? _(I know it is a restore only, but your account could make this error if you don't set the correct settings of your account.)_

Comment: I tried to edit our account and we already purchased an item. I think it has the correct settings. But, I just got this new error : Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=1005 "This is not a Test User account." UserInfo=0x95baa30 {NSLocalizedDescription=This is not a Test User account.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241 StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem while testing from the simulator. Try it on a physical device since in-app purchases are not available on simulator.

Answer (score 2):

From the "In-App Purchase Programming Guide": Store Kit does not operate in iOS Simulator. When running your application in iOS Simulator, Store Kit logs a warning if your application attempts to retrieve the payment queue. Testing the store must be done on actual devices.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html

Comment: No, in-app purchase can be tested in simulator with test accounts. In the link you provided you can see "Store Kit can be tested in the iOS simulator, except for hosted content downloads."

Comment: Apparently, it depends on when you last tested. Now, it doesn't work even with a test account. Before it did work. The doc didn't change, neither my code.

Answer (score 0):

inapp purchase is available in simulator so you can check it in simulator.