# "Cannot connect to iTunes store" when restoring iOS In App Purchase in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've looked through the many existing questions related to "Cannot connect to iTunes store" issues with iOS StoreKit and I don't think my situation is covered:

When running in the iOS Simulator, I get the "Cannot connect to iTunes store" error after restoring a previous bought in app purchase. If I hit Cancel, the popup goes away and the restore is successful.

There is no problem at all when buying the in app purchase, only when restoring.

Also, the problem only occurs on the simulator, not when testing on a real iPhone.

I'm pretty sure everything is OK, just wanted to confirm that it is just a simulator bug. Any one else seen this one?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Having researched this as much as I can, and confirmed that there are no issues when running on a device, either in sandbox mode or (since yesterday, when the IAP was approved by Apple) using a real Apple ID, I'm assuming this is a simulator bug and can be ignored.

Contrary to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259971/368085) posted by [iLive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318213/ilive) below, and repeated elsewhere on SO, testing IAP on the simulator **is** explicitly supported by Apple, except for hosted content downloads.

**UPDATE:** It would appear that since iOS 7, testing IAP on the simulator is no longer properly supported. I've had it working using the non-64bit simulator, but not with the 64bit iPhone simulator. Your milage may vary. As per [pix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195061/pix)'s comment below, Apple also seem to have removed mention of iOS simulator testing from their documentation.

Comment: Oddly, the only place I could find on the Apple site confirming that IAP testing is supported on the iOS Simulator, is in the ["Testing a Store" section of the OSX version of the IAP Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html).
The current [iOS version of the IAP Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) doesn't contain an equivalent page ;)

Comment: @pix yes, that appears to be the case. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241 StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Answer (score 7):

I do not believe you can test your purchases with the simulator.

From the "In-App Purchase Programming Guide":

> Store Kit does not operate in iOS Simulator. When running your application in iOS Simulator, Store Kit logs a warning if your application attempts to retrieve the payment queue. Testing the store must be done on actual devices.

If you look at this link, Apple tells you about what you should do:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html

You can also check out this link: [restore button for in-app purchases error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670538/restore-button-for-in-app-purchases-error)

Hope this helped!

Comment: From the link you posted: "Note: Store Kit can be tested in the iOS Simulator, except for hosted content downloads.", which directly contradicts what you posted. I'm not doing hosted content downloads, so it should work.

Comment: This use to be true, but Apple now allows store transactions within the simulator.

Comment: In Xcode 5.1.1, I can indeed test In-App Purchase with the iOS 6.1 Simulator. But with the iOS 7.1 Simulator, a purchase transaction results in an error code 0.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.  I would get the "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".  If you press Retry it will send you to the login prompt.  However, if you press cancel, you will get "Restore Purchases Successful".  This does seem limited to the simulator.

[image: Cannot connect to iTunes Store]

[image: Restore Purchases Successful]

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use an account which is an sandbox user. I tried to use my personal iCloud account on Sandbox which got rejected with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As of recent (Version 8 and onwards) Xcode releases, I'd qualify the state of `StoreKit` in the simulator as *partially implemented*.

Apple officially says you need to test it on the device, however *some* calls seem to supported in the Simulator – at least the `SKProductRequest` always works flawlessly. Completing a purchase may or may not work.